# How to stop caching of images on apache server

Tags: php, html, css

I have been looking everywhere to solve the caching problem on a part of my website that requires the most current version of a file. This file is a background image that can be uploaded by the user. It uses a form to upload an image to a certain folder on the server. Everytime the user's page is loaded the php script echos CSS into the head tag of the page.

I know about tricks like appending a random string or time stamp to the end of the source file in the src attribute of an image. However, in my case there is no img tag. The background image is applied to a wrapper div via css:

```
#wrapper{
   background-image:url('dir/imagename.jpg');
}
```

In terms of stopping the browser caching I have tried the following:

```html
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
<meta Http-Equiv="Pragma-directive: no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-directive: no-cache">
```

That code has been added in to the head tag of the page.

I have also tried this with php:

```html
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Even after all these changes, I have to refresh the page at least a dozen times for the image to update. When downloading the image via ftp client or built in file manager I can see that the image has been updated instantly. So, I conclude that the browser (Google Chrome) is caching these images and I can't seem to interrupt or prevent this process.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can apply a random string or time stamp in the CSS file ex: <link rel="stylesheet" href="whatever.css?v=201508012250" type="text/css" media="all" />

Comment: Each HTTP request is cached separately. Your HTML, CSS and the image are all separate HTTP requests. Setting headers for one does not influence the others.

Comment: @Luis P. A There is no css file. All css code gets dynamically added to the page with php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to "uncache" the static assets like images, CSS and JavaScript. I don't know how you are sending the headers for those, coz they don't work that way. Using `.htaccess` add this rule to tell browsers not to cache `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, `.gif`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
Header set Expires "Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```