# PHP is not displaying updated data in the the web view even after the page refresh if data is modified and updated in root folder

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch, localhost

New to PHP!

So I have PHP application deployed in local xampp server and I have a .json file in root folder/JSON/.

In javascript I have a loop that runs for every 10 seconds. It fetches the locally stored json file & images and displays on the web view. If locally stored json data or if a new image is updated with same name, web view is not reflecting the changes after 10 seconds, even if the web page is refreshed the changes are not reflecting in web page.

What could be the reason. How to make it work.

```
<script>
    for(let i=0; i<n; i++){
        var nextPage = setTimeout(function() {
            fetch('json/imagePathsMappingToCodes.json') //Locally stored JSON
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then((imagePath) => {
                console.log(imagePath); //Does not reflecting changes when json is modified in the mean time to 
            }
        }, i* 10000)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Just a hunch: your browser may be loading a cached data and not the new ones

Comment: Images are caching. Yes! Then What might be the case with JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to browser caching. What happens if you do a hard refresh in your browser or if you open up your page in incognito modus?

To fix this there are several solutions:

- Force browser to download resource again (quick & dirty): you could disable caching in the .htacces of your server [(more information in this topic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222926/how-to-stop-caching-of-images-on-apache-server)
  Depending on the use case of your website this could be a really bad idea because it forces your users to download the (potential) same image again and again.
- Change the filename of the resource everytime a new version is uploaded.

Comment: Images are caching. working fine in incognito. Then what is it with the case of JSON modifications

Comment: JSON files are also cached. Add JSON to the list to uncache those as well.

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|json)$">
Header set Expires "Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>

Comment: I did not quite understand the FilesMatch syntax. Can you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: It says that all files with the extension jpg, jpeg, png, gif & json expire on 1 jan of 2000. Since this is in the past the browser of your users will redownload those files.

Comment: Please, if my answer helps you along feel free to accept it and/or upvote it. Thanks!